# How to edit image in C#

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

Heey. I wanna write a program for a report system. I wanna Show up the result in a .jpg image. 
I have many variable for name, age, sex etc etc etc.

Here comes the question..

> Why not do in Word?

Ya. This result should be in .jpg not .docx for because the image will be post on websites.

How should "put" variables onto image?

Heres a example for what i want: http://prntscr.com/s8bgze

Comment: What do you use? windowsform or wpf

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi form firstly

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
// load your photo
var photo = new Bitmap("photo.jpg");
// create an image of the desired size
var bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 300);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    // specify the desired quality of the render and text, if you wish
    //graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    //graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

    // set background color
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    // place photo on image in desired location
    graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(photo, 0, 0);

    using (var font = new Font("Arial", 12))
    {
        // draw some text on image
        graphics.DrawString("Name: X Y", font, Brushes.Black, 0, 200);
        graphics.DrawString("Age: 19", font, Brushes.Black, 0, 230);
        // etc
    }
}

// save image to file or stream
bitmap.Save("edited.phg", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Instead of [Graphics.DrawString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method you can use [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?view=netcore-3.1) (they have small differences in the drawing of the text).

Also, do not use jpg format for images containing text. Instead, take png.